# Difference between server side and client side high and low write watermarks options in netty 4

Tags: java, netty

[Netty best practices (slides w/ video) by Norman Maurer](http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-twitter-meetup-netty/slides.html#10.0) introduces the `WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK` and `WRITE_BUFFER_LOW_WATER_MARK` option. It also gives and example:

```
//Server
ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
bootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK, 32 * 1024);
bootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_LOW_WATER_MARK, 8 * 1024);

//Client
Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK, 32 * 1024);
bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_LOW_WATER_MARK, 8 * 1024);
```

There is also another [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281124/netty-4-high-and-low-write-watermarks) on this topic on StackOverflow. But I'm still not sure about some details.

Do the high and low write watermarks options set in client side control the behaviour of the queue written from client to server, and the server side options control the behaviour of the queue written from server to client?

Which means if the server side high watermarks options is set, then the server side channel which writes data to client becomes not writable when the client receives slowly and the previously written data has filled the queue? And vice versa for client side options.

BTW, I'm using netty 4.1.0CR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which means if the server side high watermarks options is set, then
>   the server side channel which writes data to client becomes not
>   writable when the client receives slowly and the previously written
>   data has filled the queue? And vice versa for client side options.

Once the data in the channel reaches high watermark the [channel.isWritable](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html#isWritable()) method starts returning false until the channel reaches low watermark again.

But then, if we don't check/ignore [channel.isWritable](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html#isWritable()) status and keep writing to channel even after it reaches high watermark, it could ultimately result in OOM error as indicated in the two previous slides.

**UPDATE**

> Do the high and low write watermarks options set in client side
>   control the behaviour of the queue written from client to server, and
>   the server side options control the behaviour of the queue written
>   from server to client?

That is absolutely true.

Comment: I'm aware of what you said. What I am asking is the difference between that option applying to sever side and client server.

Comment: @WeiboLi Please see my update section in the answer.